# Detect when a user unfocuses on an input box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

Is it possible to detect when the user unfocuses an input box using jquery? I.e when they click off of it an event fires.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function is what you are looking for.

```
$( "input[type=text]" ).blur( function() {
    // unfocus event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The *blur* event will fire any time an element loses focus.

If you are trying to determine when any input element on the page loses focus, then use **input** as your selector.

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    //This event fires every time any input element on the page loses focus
});
```

If you are only trying to determine when a particular input element on the page loses focus, then using the element's id is the most efficient jQuery selector.

```
$("#exampleID").blur(function() {
    //This event fires if the element with an id of "exampleID" loses focus
});
```