# How to unfocus ion-input when enter is hit

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, blur

I have an ion-input to allow users to add text comments.
I wish that when the text is not empty and user hits `enter`, the ion-input is unfocused automatically. Of course, I will implement logic to save the comment text to DB and show back in the page.

I tried both `event.blur()` and `textInput.nativeElement.blur()`, but not working.
How to unfocus?

```
  commentHandler(event) {
    const keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 13 && this.commentText != "") {
      this.logger.info("enter hit");
      event.blur();
      // this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();
    }
  }

<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Add comment, then hit enter</ion-label>
    <ion-input #commentInput type="text" (keypress)="commentHandler($event)" ngModel="commentText"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Try this using `javascript` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245517/detect-when-a-user-unfocuses-on-an-input-box-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for posting. This will be my plan B as I am looking for an Ionic way to do so first :).

Comment: This can resolve your problem - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5487

Comment: ionic way is to use [input.setBlur](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/efd54750bf44b622a20078be02a2335aabc6dcec/src/components/input/input.ts#L388) if this does not work for you, you should report an issue to ionic team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and trying different things, this seems to work for me. Hope it helps.

**myPage.ts:**

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

export class MyPage {
    @ViewChild('chatInput') chatInput: ElementRef;

    myFunction() {
        this.chatInput['_native'].nativeElement.blur();
    }
}
```

**myPage.html:**

```
<ion-input #chatInput ></ion-input>
```

Inspired by this page (but their solution did not work for me):
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-force-blur-on-ion-input/64038/6

Comment: i cannot verify your solution as i dont use ionic now. Mark it as a solution to clap for your sharing :)

Comment: in ionic-5, it works. `https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-force-blur-on-ion-input/64038/13`